# Gradle + Intellij IDEA 13 bug

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jetty

I'm trying to setup simple webapp with gradle 1.7, jetty 9.2 and intellij IDEA 13.

Here some typical config lines of gradle build found in tutorials I'm using:

```
apply plugin: 'jetty'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    // other dependencies
}
```

Configuration to launch in IDEA is in `Edit Configurations...->Add->Gradle`, task is `jettyRun`.
For the first run all works fine, jetty starts, the webapp is availailable in a browser.
But if I change something in the `gradle.build` file and rerun the task following error will occur:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'gr3'.
Could not open buildscript class cache for build file 'D:\Work\priv\gr3\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Sazankov_LY\.gradle\caches\1.7\scripts\build_546r8n6d85n2abfbi95h2qqmh4\ProjectScript\buildscript).

Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file 'D:\Work\priv\gr3\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Sazankov_LY\.gradle\caches\1.7\scripts\build_546r8n6d85n2abfbi95h2qqmh4\ProjectScript\buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: unknown
     Our PID: 11948
     Owner Operation: unknown
     Our operation: 
     Lock file: C:\Users\Sazankov_LY\.gradle\caches\1.7\scripts\build_546r8n6d85n2abfbi95h2qqmh4\ProjectScript\buildscript\cache.properties.lock
```

The only way to continue working is restarting IDE

Any ideas?

Comment: If you click on the refresh button (double blue spinning arrows) in the IntelliJ Gradle tasks box does it fix the problem?

Comment: No, the same error occurs: 
`Gradle 'grdl2' project refresh failed:
Timeout waiting...`

Comment: Maybe try removing `.gradle` folder in project folder?

Comment: Are you tied to version 1.7?  Gradle v2.0 was just released and they are toting their improved IDE integration in the release notes.  Even if you can't upgrade, perhaps give it a try to see if 2 can fix it.  Also ensure intellij is use the expected version for gradle under IDE --> Setting --> Gradle --> "Gradle home:" (there is an 'auto-import' checkbox there too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I've found out that problem is in correct terminating jetty. If you stop jetty by "Terminate" button on IDEA's toolbar, lock remains on the cache file. So you need to stop jetty via `jettyStop` task. Also you need to specify `stopKey` and `stopPort` for successful task executing.

Answer (score 4):

delete the lock file

```
sudo rm -f <lockfile>
```

kill the pid

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Try again

```
gradle jettyRun -PbuildProfile=<profile>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue when multiple builds are running from the same build.gradle file, see https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2795

Not sure if IntelliJ allows that, but one possible workaround is to use the commandline option --gradle-user-home to specify a different Gradle dir, with the downside that it will download all dependencies again into this directory.

There are other workarounds described in the issue, although I did not try any of those.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

'jcenter' must keep!

Comment: Please provide a description that explains, why you think this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to tackle this technically but you can do this manually.

1. Restart your computer.
2. Go to your project folder and find the `.gradle` folder.
3. Go in and delete the `cache.properties.lock` file
4. Come back out and then find the `.gradle` folder in the users for the Windows platform
5. Go in the `caches` folder and look for the `modules-2` folder delete the `modules-2.lock` file inside.
6. Start your Android Studio normally

This is what I did and it works for me.
Maybe this happens when you force close the build process, so no other process can use this again until you reboot.